# Swift App with SQLITE crashes after updating DB. SQLITE file is not copied to file/bundle

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

My app worked perfectly until I used a new SQLite browser do do some changes in my sqlite file. Then there suddenly is a problem with opening the database. 
The database opening function look like this:

```
func openDatabase() -> Bool {
        do {
            let manager = FileManager.default

            let documentsURL = try manager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("database.sqlite")
            var rc = sqlite3_open_v2(documentsURL.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil)
            if rc == SQLITE_CANTOPEN {
                let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "database", withExtension: "sqlite")!
                try manager.copyItem(at: bundleURL, to: documentsURL)
                rc = sqlite3_open_v2(documentsURL.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil)
            }

            if rc != SQLITE_OK {
                print("Error: \(rc)")
                return false
            }
            return true
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return false
        }     
    }
```

After making a change in the DB with *DB Browser for sqlite*, the app crashes the moment the databese is opened, pointing out that this line gives an unexpected nil while unwrapping optional value:

```
 let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "database", withExtension: "sqlite")!
```

Log gives following text:

```
2018-12-20 18:16:22.306631+0100 eFloraSnap[7844:165367] [logging-persist] cannot open file at line 42249 of [95fbac39ba]
2018-12-20 18:16:22.306810+0100 eFloraSnap[7844:165367] [logging-persist] os_unix.c:42249: (0) open(/Users/tomsol/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/143DCE6E-01F0-40D0-9640-6397504D81FA/data/Containers/Data/Application/6BB619CB-BEF9-4917-9A74-8C92D84DA2F0/Documents/database.sqlite) - Undefined error: 0
(lldb)
```

I dont get it. I totally uninstalled Xcode with "Clean My Mac" ann reinstalled Xcode from scratch, in hope of removing som bad settings. This did not solve anything. Thinking there might be a problem with some databse formatting.

Is there any other reason this happens?

EDIT:
I have now seen, that the databse.sqlite is not in the path given in the log. So why is the sqlite file not copied there when building and running? Same problem with device as simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like completely uninstalling Xcode does not fixes bad settings.
Adding the sqlite file in Buildphases-Copy bundle resources fixed it. Why it disappered from copy bundle resources in the first time is unknown. Why it wasnt autmatically added using a freshly installed xcode is also unknown.